# Mongo sub document population

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, documents

Hello I have three models

Posts:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: '',
},
content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: '',
},
community: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
},
price: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: '',
},
location: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: '',
},
images: {
    type:[],
    required: true,
},
user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User',
},
accepted : {
    type: [],
},
comments: {
    type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref:"Comment"
}
});
```

Users:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

local            : {
    email        : String,       
    password     : String,
},

firstName: { type: String, required: true },
lastName: { type: String, required: true },
location: { type: String, required: true },
profilepicture: { type: String },

});
```

Comments

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
},
content: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
},
user: { 
    type: Schema.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'User' 
},
post: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post'
},
offer: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
}
});
```

I am trying to allow the Posts model to have an object id array of comments and for the comments to have there user objectid populated. I am using the below code for my posts route and I can get all the comments to populate but I cant get the user of the comment to populate.In theory this should work according to the mongo docs, but its not. Any ideas?

```
app.get('/api/posts', function(req, res) {

Post.find().populate('user comments comments.user').exec(function(err, posts) {
    if (err) {
        res.render('error', {
            status: 500
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(posts);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Was there something in the answer that does not fully answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, you would need to call populate on the inner "comments" object after the initial populate call has bee done. In a simplified version of your listing:

```
var async = require("async"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/user");

var postSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true, default: '' },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
  comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comment" }]
});

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

var commentSchema = new Schema({
  content: String,
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }
});

var Post = mongoose.model( "Post", postSchema );
var User = mongoose.model( "User", userSchema );
var Comment = mongoose.model( "Comment", commentSchema );
```

Populating the "user" on the comments would be like this:

```
Post.find().populate("user comments").exec(function(err,docs) {

    async.forEach(docs,function(doc,callback) {
      Comment.populate( doc.comments,{ "path": "user" },function(err,output) {
        //console.log( "doc: " + doc );
        //console.log( "proc: " + output );
        callback();
      });

    },function(err) {
      console.log( "all: " + JSON.stringify(docs,undefined,4 ));
    });

});
```

Or however you are actually processing the results from your find on the post. The point is that your "comments" needs to be populated first and then you can call [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate),  using the the model form, on the whole "comments" array per document in the result.